# "Why can't I install React correctly?"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mern

C\Windows\System32\cmd.e X +

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2715] (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user\Desktop\React>npx create-react-app employee_app

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall Istat

npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, Istat 'C:\Users\user\A ata\Roaming\npm'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\user\AppData

ocal\npm-cache_logs\2023-12-22T17_12_07_950Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\user\Desktop\React>

i tried to install but its showing some errors. i checked the node version and npm version its upto date

Comment: Are you using VSCode?

Comment: Hello Subin. Even though I don't know how to solve the issue, I feel for you. I find the installation process quite tricky. I wish you the best of luck and hope someone else on this platform can help you out!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm cache clean`
if this doesnt resolve it, I would reinstall node